# Elementary question: local computation of curvature on principal bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, gauge-theory

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $S=[0,1]^2$. Let $\omega$ be a connection $1$-form on the trivial principal $G-$bundle $P=S\times G$ over $S$. Let $(x_1,x_2)$ be coordinates on the base $S$.

We can choose a trivialization of $P$ which is parallel with respect to the $x_1-$direction over the $x_1-$axis (aka $[0,1]\times\{0\}$) and which is parallel in the $x_2-$direction at every point of $S$.

Then $\omega=A_1dx_1+A_2dx_2$ where $A_i\in\mathfrak{g}$ satisfy $A_2=0$ everywhere and $A_1|_{[0,1]\times\{0\}}=0$.

Denote the horizontal lift of a vector field $\chi$ on the base to $P$ as $\tilde{\chi}$. Let $\sigma$ be the vertical projection on $P$ given by $\omega$.

Let $\chi_i=\partial_{x_i}$ then $\tilde{\chi_2}=\partial_{x_2}$ and $\tilde{\chi_1}|_{[0,1]\times\{0\}}=\partial_{x_1}$.

> How to show that $\sigma([\tilde{\chi_1},\tilde{\chi_2}])=-\partial A_1/\partial x_2$ at $(0,0)\in S$?

I mean, it doesn't make sense since $\omega|_{(0,0)}=0$, is it not? Where is my misunderstanding?

This is taken from page $73$ of the book "Gauge Theory and the Topology of Four-Manifolds" by Friedman and Morgan. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to calculate curvature is to note that the curvature satisfies the Cartan structure equation, $F_A = d\omega + [\omega, \omega]$. Note the first term! Just because $\omega$ is zero at some point doesn't mean its *derivative* is.

In particular, we see that at $(0,0)$ where $\omega = 0$, that $F_A = d\omega = (\partial A_2/\partial x_1 - \partial A_1/\partial x_2) dx_1 \wedge dx_2$; and applying this to the 2-vector $(\partial/\partial x_1, \partial/\partial x_2)$, because $A_2 = 0$, we get what you desire.

Comment: The book I mention has not derived the formula $F_A=d\omega+[\omega,\omega]$ yet. It seems that it is clear the output is $-\partial A_1/\partial x_2(0,0)$ but I just don't see it.

Comment: @HLC At the very least, this should convince you that because $\omega=0$ somewhere doesn't mean the curvature is also zero there.

Comment: @HLC Exactly. Sorry for not writing this in my answer earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was being stupid. Thank you for clarifying to me. By the way, there was a typo in my question. I think I understand this now. We have $d\omega(\tilde{\chi_1},\tilde{\chi_2})=\tilde{\chi_1}(\omega(\tilde{\chi_2}))-\tilde{\chi_2}(\omega(\tilde{\chi_1}))-\omega([\tilde{\chi_1},\tilde{\chi_2}])=-\omega([\tilde{\chi_1},\tilde{\chi_2}])$ since $\tilde{\chi_i}$ are horizontal and the rest follows as you said.